# XMLhttprequest gets '404 not found' but invoke-webrequest runs fine

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, citrix

I'm trying to run a Citrix application from javascript code. I've got a sample that works fine with powershell, just showing first call:

```
#Gets required tokens
$headers = @{
"Accept"='application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01';
"Content-Length"="0";
"X-Requested-With"="XMLHttpRequest";
"X-Citrix-IsUsingHTTPS"="Yes";
"Referer"=$sfurl;
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($sfurl + "Home/Configuration") -Method POST -Headers $headers -WebSession $sfsession|Out-Null

$csrf = $sfsession.cookies.GetCookies($sfurl)|where{$_.name -like "CsrfToken"}
$cookiedomain = $csrf.Domain
write-host $csrf.Domain
```

that piece of code works fine, and we can see the value provided from citrix server but if I translate it to javascript I only get error '404 Not Found'. Javascript piece of code is also simple:

```
function starticaurl (authurl, whatapp) {
    var csrf = getCookie("CsrfToken");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", (authurl + "Home/Configuration"), true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length","0");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Citrix-IsUsingHTTPS","Yes");
    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Referer",authurl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Csrf-Token',csrf);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // do something to response
        console.log(this.responseText);
    };

    xhr.send();

    console.log("Got: " + csrf);
```

csrf is always 'null'. This function is called from a simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>     
</head> 

<body>    
    <h1>ICA Launcher</h1>
    <script src="createica.js"></script>

    <button onclick="starticaurl('https://citrix.mycompany.com/Citrix/TestWeb/', 'Notepad')">Launch App</button>
</body>    
</html>
```

I don't understand why browser is always returning this 404 error when from powerhell same URL is working fine.

Any idea ?

Comment: you try to get the cookie before posting . you should post and then get the cookie

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, but I think that issue comes later. To  me the root cause comes from browser itself. What I want to understand is why same request works from PowerShell using invoke-webrequest cmdlet but not able to run with a this javascript call.

Comment: When you run Powershell commands you don't have the browser limitation. if you want to avoid this and still use javascript, you need to create Node.js server and post the request from there.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed before behavior is because the browser. It requires valid CORS headers from server so it is needed to start Chrome with --disable-web-security to bypass and test. Also to point I've wasted time because the server error is '404 Not found' instead of forbidden or something else...

I understand also that powershell cmdlet invoke-webrequest is not subject to CORS restrictions at all.